# Advantage of using @EJB to inject @Stateless Bean or using directly @inject

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ear

I am working on an old project developed in EJB.

I have serviceImpl as `@Stateless(mappedName = "adminService")`. I have seen in my project injecting this class in other classes by

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:app/adminServices/adminServiceImpl")
```

and other classes are part of the same EAR but different modules. This serviceImpl class is being used only in this EAR.

So my question is if we have a class that is declared as `@Stateless` and is not being used in other EAR. This class is being used in same EAR modules. So can't we directly use `@Inject` without declaring it @Stateless?

I have known for three JNDI syntax for EJB

`java:global[/application name]/module name/enterprise bean name[/interface name]`

`java:module/enterprise bean name/[interface name]`

`java:app[/module name]/enterprise bean name[/interface name]`

Can't I use `@Inject` for `java:app`?

Why do I need `java:module` in the same modules, I can directly create an object or use `@Inject`.

In case of `java:global` I can understand if you are in other JVM then you need to make RMI call to get an object if stateless bean instance is in other JVM. So I have to use `java:global` syntax to get stateless bean instance from other JVM even in same JVM. Because I don't think We can use `@Inject` to get the instance from another EAR project into your EAR.

But in same JVM and same EAR, what is need of java:app and java:module JNDI syntax to get the instance by `@EJB` annotation if the bean is not `singleton`. 
I can directly use `@Inject`.

Comment: the jndi references are most likely disambiguations.  if youre EJB is being injected into an interface reference, there could be other implementations, and the jndi ref will give you a specific proxy binding rather than "first come, first serve" or the container complaining about having multiple impls to choose from.